# Optimisation in badly-performing query

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I have the following query which is working correctly, however it is running very poorly. I am suspecting that my issue is with the two comparison conditions in the INNER JOIN statement. Both of the fields have an index, but the query optimiser in MySQL seems to be ignoring them.  Here is my query:

**EDIT:** **Changed query to use the one suggested below by Gordon, as it has kept the same results but is performing faster. EXPLAIN statement is still not happy though, and the output is shown below.**

```
    SELECT a.id
FROM pc a INNER JOIN
     (SELECT correction_value, MAX(seenDate) mxdate
      FROM pc FORCE INDEX (IDX_SEENDATE)
      WHERE seenDate BETWEEN '2017-03-01' AND '2017-04-01'
      GROUP BY correction_value
     ) b
     ON a.correction_value = b.correction_value AND
        a.seenDate = b.mxdate INNER JOIN
     cameras c
     ON c.camera_id = a.camerauid
WHERE c.in_out = 0;
```

**EXPLAIN**

```
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+-------------------+--------------+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type  | possible_keys     | key          | key_len | ref      | rows    | filtered | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+-------------------+--------------+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | NULL       | ALL   | NULL              | NULL         |    NULL | NULL     | 2414394 |      100 | Using where;              |
|    |             |            |            |       |                   |              |         |          |         |          | Using temporary;              |
|    |             |            |            |       |                   |              |         |          |         |          | Using filesort            |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+-------------------+--------------+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | a          | NULL       | ref   | correction_value, | idx_seenDate |       5 | b.mxdate |       1 |      3.8 | Using where               |
|    |             |            |            |       | idx_seenDate,     |              |         |          |         |          |                       |
|    |             |            |            |       | fk_camera_idx     |              |         |          |         |          |                       |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+-------------------+--------------+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | c          | NULL       | ALL   | PRIMARY           | NULL         |    NULL | NULL     |      41 |     2.44 | Using where;              |
|    |             |            |            |       |                   |              |         |          |         |          | Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+-------------------+--------------+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------------------------------------+
|  2 | DERIVED     | pc         | NULL       | range | correction_value, | idx_seenDate |       5 | NULL     | 2414394 |      100 | Using index Condition;        |
|    |             |            |            |       | idx_seenDate      |              |         |          |         |          | Using temporary;              |
|    |             |            |            |       |                   |              |         |          |         |          | Using filesort            |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+-------------------+--------------+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------------------------------------+
```

How can the query be optimised but still have the same outcome?

Comment: in_out column belong from which table ??

Comment: @AshutoshSIngh - cameras table. But that is irrelevant because the performance issue is in the inner join condition.

Comment: What column is `in_out` in?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - cameras table. Updated the question.

Comment: What are the indexes that you have on pc table and what is the column order? Also can you please put the EXPLAIN output.

Comment: @Aruna - added EXPLAIN to question.

Comment: I'm surprised that no one else has mentioned this already, but, as well as the EXPLAIN, questions about query optimisation ALWAYS require CREATE TABLE statements for ALL relevant tables.

Comment: @MathLover it seems the problem is with the number of rows need to be analysed on pc table. Even though you have an index on the table it still have to analyse 2.4 million records. That anyway will take time. Is there any other filters that you can reduce the number of records?  BTW, how many records that you have on pc table? also what is the column order of idx_seenDate?

Comment: The numbers imply that all values of `correction_value` are different.  Are they?

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: @RickJames - Latest

Comment: @MathLover create index on cameras.camera_id then use that index with JOIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start by focusing on the subquery.

```
SELECT  correction_value,
        MAX(seenDate) mxdate
    FROM  pc
    WHERE  seenDate BETWEEN '2017-03-01' AND '2017-04-01'
    GROUP BY  correction_value
```

Please run that with twice, with

```
INDEX sc (seenDate, correction_value)
INDEX cs (correction_value, seenDate)
```

Please FORCE one index, then the other.  Depending on what version of MySQL you are running, one of the indexes will work better than the other.

I *think* that later versions will prefer "cs" because it can leapfrog through the index very efficiently.

Once you have determined which composite index to use, then remove the `FORCE` and the unused index, then try the entire query.  The *same* index should do fine for the combined query.

Since your task seems to involve a "groupwise max", I suggest you see if there are performance tips here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT 
    a.id
FROM pc a
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT  correction_value, MAX(seenDate) mxdate
FROM pc
INNER JOIN cameras ON (cameras.camera_id = pc.camerauid AND cameras.in_out = 0)
WHERE pc.seenDate BETWEEN '2017-03-01' AND '2017-04-01'
GROUP BY correction_value) b ON (a.correction_value = b.correction_value AND a.seenDate = b.mxdate);
```

use index on pc.seenDate column.

Comment: At what part should the index be put?

Comment: I placed it after the join on PC, however it is still quite unoptimised

Comment: Have you any idea about query execution with explain, when you execute explain query it will give which table is using which index and what is possible index and etc.

Comment: THe results being returned are different to my original query now. The issue is regarding the placement of the WHERE in_out = 0 clause. It has to be after the grouping.

Comment: I think you have turned a derived subquery into a correlated subquery.  And that means that the subquery will need to be run 2.4 million times.  Not a pretty picture.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by writing the query as:

```
SELECT a.id
FROM pc a INNER JOIN
     (SELECT correction_value, MAX(seenDate) mxdate
      FROM pc
      WHERE seenDate BETWEEN '2017-03-01' AND '2017-04-01'
      GROUP BY correction_value
     ) b
     ON a.correction_value = b.correction_value AND
        a.seenDate = b.mxdate INNER JOIN
     cameras c
     ON c.camera_id = a.camerauid
WHERE c.in_out = 0;  - don't use single quotes if `in_out` is a number
```

The place to start with this query is to have indexes:  `pc(seendate, correction_value, seendate)` and `cameras(camera_id, in_out)`.

There may also be ways to rewrite the query, if that is not sufficient.

Comment: This has improved the performance and kept the same results, but the EXPLAIN is still not happy.  I will update my question to use this query and also show the EXPLAIN result.

Comment: I also added a FORCE INDEX as shown in the edited question, which helped improve the EXPLAIN.

Comment: Minor note:  The one combination that is "bad" is comparing a varchar to an unquoted number.  That is, `c.in_out = '0'` would convert the `'0'` to `0` when compiling the query.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it is not clear how the tables are indexed, but in this subquery

```
(SELECT correction_value, MAX(seenDate) mxdate
  FROM pc FORCE INDEX (IDX_SEENDATE)
  WHERE seenDate BETWEEN '2017-03-01' AND '2017-04-01'
  GROUP BY correction_value
 ) b
```

you want to have a composite index on both fields `seenDate, correction_value`:

```
CREATE INDEX seenCorr_ndx ON pc (seenDate, correction_value);
```

(you can drop any index on `seenDate` alone, and I expect you do not need the FORCE INDEX either).

You may end up needing two composite indexes, one with `seenDate` first, one with `correction_value` first.

Comment: Minor note:  I think "composite index" is the standard term.

Answer (score 0):

**RDBMS** uses the output of the first query as a input of the next query. So, if we look at the derived query, it is using a filter so we can use that as a **first query**, then join to the **pc** then join to the **camera** table.

Indexes: mentioned by **Gordon Linof** or pc(id, correction_value, seendate) and cameras(camera_id, in_out)

The final query could be rewrite as below:

```
SELECT a.id 
 --add any other column here, you want to show in the EXPLAINED output
FROM
(
    SELECT id, correction_value, MAX(seenDate) mxdate
    FROM pc
    WHERE seenDate BETWEEN '2017-03-01' AND '2017-04-01'
    GROUP BY correction_value
) a 
INNER JOIN pc b
        ON a.correction_value = b.correction_value 
        AND a.seenDate = b.mxdate 
INNER JOIN cameras c
        ON c.camera_id = a.camerauid
WHERE c.in_out = 0;
```

Comment: This is MySQL so does not seem to support the WITH clause.